# Image Dataset for testing

Tags: image-processing

Can some refer me to a good image dataset with multiple classes and has images for training and testing data at the same place ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the use case? Since images are vary greatly typically there is a category of images. In the simplist case if you only need multiple classes then you could synthetically create a dataset with the background color being the class (I'm guessing that you're looking for more than this). Also, you'll usually find a full dataset and then you decide what is training and what is testing by randomly separating some of the images.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know, what's your intention. Here are some recommendations.

ALOI: http://staff.science.uva.nl/~aloi/

Microsoft Research Cambridge Object Recognition Image Database: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b94de342-60dc-45d0-830b-9f6eff91b301/default.aspx

The PASCAL Visual Object Classes Homepage: http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/